# Как получить иконку папки?

Tags: c#

Как получить иконку папки?

Например

Control Panel

```
Shell:::{5399E694-6CE5-4D6C-8FCE-1D8870FDCBA0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего использовать Windows API Code Pack, чтобы не возиться с interop'ом и COM-объектами. Если у вас Visual Studio версии до 2017, вам нужно будет вручную подключить nuget-пакет [Windows API Code Pack - Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/). (2017-ая студия найдёт и предложит подключить пакет сама, увидев незнакомый тип.)

Подключив пакет, мы сможем работать с типами `ShellObject` или `ShellFolder`. Для того, чтобы получить сам каталог, нам нужно написать, например,

```
(ShellFolder)ShellObject.FromParsingName("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
```

`ShellFolder` является списком своих подобъектов, поэтому перечислить подобъекты можно просто так:

```
var sf = (ShellFolder)ShellObject.FromParsingName(
                            "shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
Console.WriteLine(sf.Name);
foreach (var item in sf)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    ShellThumbnail t = item.Thumbnail;
}
```

Иконка подкаталога содержится в объекте `ShellThumbnail`. Сам объект содержит иконки в различных форматах (icon, WPF `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` и WinForms `System.Drawing.Bitmap`) и различных размерах. Для отображения нам понадобится графическое приложение. Я воспользуюсь более простым WPF.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ShellObject.FromParsingName(
                            "shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="ShellReaderWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Name}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail.MediumBitmapSource}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Padding="10"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: приложухи]